# How to make movement independent of rotation of the object? C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make my capsule move, but when I rotate the camera, its movement becomes inverted. What should I change?

Here's my code

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ejimaslol : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Rigidbody rb;
    public Transform rotation;
    public float forwardForce = 1f;
    public float sidewaysForce = 1f;


    void FixedUpdate()
    {
     if(Input.GetKey("w") ){
         rb.AddForce((forwardForce, 0f, 0f) * rotation.transform.rotation);
        }
    if(Input.GetKey("d") ){
            rb.AddForce((sidewaysForce, 0f, 0f) * rotation.transform.rotation);
        }
        if(Input.GetKey("a") ){
            rb.AddForce((-sidewaysForce, 0f, 0f) * rotation.transform.rotation);
        }
         if(Input.GetKey("s"))
        {
            rb.AddForce((-forwardForce, 0f, 0f) * rotation.transform.rotation);
        }```
````

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to make those directions **relative to camera** and not object itself:

```
float dt = Time.fixedDeltaTime;
float forcePerSecond = 10f;
var cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;
if( Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) )
    rb.AddForce( Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(cameraTransform.forward,Vector3.up).normalized * forcePerSecond * dt );
if( Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) )
    rb.AddForce( Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(-cameraTransform.forward,Vector3.up).normalized * forcePerSecond * dt );
```